# Can you estimate the number of servers on a queue from the average waiting time?

Tags: poisson-distribution, operations-research, queueing-theory

How do you estimate the number of servers serving a single queue?

I know that on average a job should take `j` seconds to complete and jobs arrive under some poisson distribution. I also know on average how long a job takes including time in the queue `k` seconds.

Comment: The "common sense" estimate, I would think, is $k/j$: if *every* job takes exactly $j$ seconds and every job is in the queue for exactly $k$ seconds, then there are on average $k/j$ jobs on the queue.

Answer (score 0):

If you assume Markovian service times as well as a Poisson arrival process, you have an M/M/c system (where c is the number of servers. See the corresponding [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M/M/c_queue). You can get a point estimate of the number of servers from the standard formulas. There's no guarantee that the point estimate is an integer, so you may need to massage it a little, but it should be in the ballpark.